# How can I migrate from MVC5 to MVC4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, versioning, asp.net-mvc-migration

I want to migrate from MVC5 to MVC4, because my server is not supporting MVC 5 and giving me so many issues, 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best thing to do is probably create a new MVC 4 project and then drag all the files from MVC 5, except for web.configs, into that solution.

If you are using NuGet to use MVC 5 you could also try uninstalling the mvc 5 nuget package and then installing the specific version of MVC 4 you want via :

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc -Version 4.0.30506
```